# Join on pattern matching

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have the following data tables:

```
> measures
    source     measure
1:   my123  0.08130182
2:   123my -1.45285168
3: your123 -0.30460771
4: 123your  0.94670380
5: 12your3 -0.54728546
> sources
          name pattern
1:   My Source      my
2: Your Source    your
```

created using

```
measures <- data.table(source=c('my123', '123my', 'your123', '123your', '12your3'), measure=rnorm(5))
sources <- data.table(name=c('My Source', 'Your Source'), pattern=c('my', 'your'))
```

I'd like to be able to join on `like(measures.source, sources.pattern)`. Is there a good way to do this (without having to do cross join and filter non-matching rows. This will be impractical on my data set)

I can do this in SQL (PostgreSQL, see below), but I'm wondering is there a way to do it in R's `data.table` or any plans to introduce more custom joining functionality in the future.

```
drop table if exists measures;
create table measures as (select * from (values
  ('my123', 0.08130182),
  ('123my', -1.45285168),
  ('your123', -0.30460771),
  ('123your', 0.94670380),
  ('your123', 0.94670380)
)t(source, measure));

drop table if exists sources;
create table sources as (select * from (values
  ('My Source',  'my'),
  ('Your Sources', 'your')
)t(name, pattern));

select * from measures join sources on measures.source ~ sources.pattern;
```

and this returns the required:

```
source  |   measure   |     name     | pattern
--------+-------------+--------------+---------
my123   |  0.08130182 | My Source    | my
123my   | -1.45285168 | My Source    | my
your123 | -0.30460771 | Your Sources | your
123your |  0.94670380 | Your Sources | your
your123 |  0.94670380 | Your Sources | your
```

Comment: I assume you really meant `measures.source`   not `measures.name`

Comment: There's an open FR for this https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1431 labeled high priority, fwiw.

Comment: @G5W thanks, I fixed it

Comment: @Frank thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this falls under "impractical" or not, but this will do it... and for your purposes with more complex pattern matching stringi will handle the collator.

```
> rbind.pages(lapply(1:nrow(measures), function(i){
       matched_slice <- which(stri_detect_regex(measures[i,1],sources$pattern))
       data.frame(measures[i,], sources[matched_slice, ])
  }))
   source     measure        name pattern
1   my123  0.75119183   My Source      my
2   123my  0.55344334   My Source      my
3 your123 -0.03498414 Your Source    your
4 123your  0.09364795 Your Source    your
5 12your3  0.47537732 Your Source    your
```

And for larger data sets run this with `parallel::mclapply` or for the `data.table`-ish way:

```
rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(measures), function(i){
    matched_slice <- which(stri_detect_regex(measures[i,1],sources$pattern))
    cbind(measures[i,], sources[matched_slice, ])
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's unfortunately still not feasible for me as it takes too long on the dataset I'm working on.